# How do I add a customer ID field in Ubercart?

Tags: 7, ubercart

I want to ask for the customer to enter his ID when he buys something.
Is it hard to add a new field apart from the default: name, phone, address, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add a field to the checkout process? There are two modules that do that. [uc_webform_pane](http://drupal.org/project/uc_webform_pane) allows you to create webform nodes that integrate into the checkout process. [uc_cck_pane](http://drupal.org/project/uc_cck_pane) allows you to integrate cck nodes into the checkout process.